# Using a MouseListener in an extended class

Tags: java, swing

I have a class which extends `JPanel` and contains a `JLabel` with a `MouseListener`.  I have a subclass which extends this, and I would it to have the same `JLabel`, but I would like the `MouseListener` to perform a different action. The code look something like this:

```
public class FirstClass extends JPanel{
   JLabel set1;

   public FirstClass(){
   set1 = new JLabel("Button 1");
      set1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("MouseEventOne");
     }
      });
   this.add(set1);
   }
}
```

Then:

```
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

   public SecondClass(){
   set1.setText("Button 2");
      set1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Different MouseEvent");
     }
      });
   }
}
```

So when I do this the text changes and everything looks good, but it executes both mouse listeners. Is there a way to do it so it only executes the event that corresponds to the panel the program is currently displaying? Shouldn't the `addMouseListener()` in the subclass override the one in the parent class? I only included the code that's relevant to the question, note that the JPanel stuff all works etc. it's just the listener that is giving me a problem. If I missed any info please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`addMouseListener` does exactly what it sounds like, it adds another `MouseListener`.  Java calls the default constructor of your `FirstClass` from your `SecondClass` automatically before executing any of your other code, otherwise `set1` would be `null`...

In your base class, create method something like `mouseWasClicked(MouseEvent evt)` and use the `MouseListener#mouseClcked` to call it.

In you extended class, override the `mouseWasClicked` method to do whatever else you want to do

Comment: Ok cool. I actually had it working using a string which I set to the name of the current class in each constructor, then put an IF statement in the parent class and just didn't change the listener in the sub class.but it seemed like a crappy way to do it. I'll do it using your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have two constructor for `FirstClass`, one of which takes a `MouseListener` argument.  Use the second constructor from `SecondClass`.

```
public class FirstClass extends JPanel{
    JLabel set1;

    public FirstClass(){
        this(new MouseAdaptor() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("MouseEventOne");
            }
        });
    }

    protected FirstClass(MouseListener listener) {
        set1 = new JLabel("Button 1");
        set1.addMouseListener(listener);
        this.add(set1);
    }
}
```

And then

```
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    public SecondClass() {
        super(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Different MouseEvent");
            }
        });

        set1.setText("Button 2");
    }
}
```